Sklearn PLS attributes X_scores, X_weights, X_Loadings meaning
tried reading the sci-kit documentation but the docs are short and not very helpful. Anyone can give a layman's term of the X and Y scores, weights, and loadings for a partial least squares regression PLS via sklearn?
